# how to get instance of the launched activity

Tags: android

Is there any way to get the instance of a launched activity(or any view in that activity )of a application in another application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll have to do with sending Intent's.

> A central design point of the Android security architecture is that no application, by default, has permission to perform any operations that would adversely impact other applications, the operating system, or the user.

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html

Comment: Thank you Kleist for reply,
Can you please explain "you'll have to do with sending Intent's", I dint understand this.

Comment: Intent's are AFAIK the way to do communication between applications.